# What are good introductory texts to symmetry groups of molecules and crystal structures?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, resource-recommendations, crystals, molecules

When reading about spectroscopy and non-linear optics I've stumbled a few times over short mentionings of symmetry groups for molecules or crystals.

E.g. to argue that a molecule like CCl$_4$ has a vanishing dipole moment as it is in the $T_d$ group, or that a non-linear susceptibility tensor has a certain symmetry as the crystal lattice obeys some symmetry.

I don't want to be an expert in symmetry groups, but I would like to know a reference where I can read up on the basics of these "atomic structure" symmetries.

I don't mind learning new math, but the text should be as applied as possible. I did not have much exposure to group theory yet and am mostly working on experimental things right now.

Comment: Seconding this. I have difficulty understanding crystal field splittings for different environments (cubic vs trigonal, for instance), and I think the explanation is in group theory.

Answer (score 0):

Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics, Tinkham

Symmetry Principles in Solid State and Molecular Physics, Lax

Group Theory and its Application to Physical Problems, Hamermesh

Principles of Condensed Matter Physics,  Chaikin

Also Dan Arovas from UCSD has a very good set of lecture notes:
https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2016/Spring/physics220/